# How to get the last character before the cursor position?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple math calculator. If the user changes the cursor position to the any other place in the text. I would like to get the last character before the cursor position and apply some commands. E.g

```
If (the last character is...){ 
    //perform this command
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to help you. You have to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no texts are highlighted or selected then

```
editText.getSelectionStart()
```

or

```
editText.getSelectionEnd()
```

returns the position of the cursor relative to the length of the text.
So you can use the relative position of the cursor to retrieve the last character before it.

EDIT: 
Suppose you have an EditText and you've named it editText.

```
String lastChar = "";
int cursorPos = editText.getSelectionStart();
if (cursorPos<=0)
{
     //The Cursor is at the beggining of the text
}
else
{
      lastChar = text.getText().charAt(text.getSelectionStart()-1) + "";
      System.out.println("The Last Character is: "+lastChar);
}
```

the String variable `lastChar` would contain the character before the cursor position.

Comment: I don't understand how i can use it to get the last character before the cursor position, please help.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I have got it working. But a little mistake is that lastChar is a character and needs to be converted to a string. How I did this...

Comment: char lastChar = txtShow1.getText().charAt(charCount -1);
    String lastText = Character.toString(lastChar);

Comment: in Java 8, concatenating a "" to character makes it a string.

Comment: if you're problem is solved, mark the answer as the correct one.